# What is index do i need?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have problems with the performance of this query. If I remove Order by section all work well. But I really want it. I tried to use many indexes but have not any results. Can you help me pls?

```
SELECT *
     FROM "refuel_request" AS "refuel_request"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "user" AS "user" ON "refuel_request"."user_id" = "user"."user_id"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "bill_qr" AS "bill_qr" ON "refuel_request"."bill_qr_id" = "bill_qr"."bill_qr_id"
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "car" AS "order.car" ON "refuel_request"."car_id" = "order.car"."car_id" 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "refuel_request_status" AS "refuel_request_status" ON "refuel_request"."refuel_request_status_id" = "refuel_request_status"."refuel_request_status_id"
     WHERE
      refuel_request."refuel_request_status_id" IN ( '1', '2', '3') 
     ORDER BY "refuel_request".created_at desc
     LIMIT 10
```

[There is explain of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb0zg.png)

[EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDIaB.png)

Primary Keys and/or Foreign Keys

1. pk_refuel_request_id
2. refuel_request_bill_qr_id_fkey
3. refuel_request_user_id_fkey

Comment: Do you have any Primary Keys and/or Foreign Keys set up? What indexes did you try? (please add those details to your question)

Comment: Thanks for including the explain plan, but could you please replace that with the result of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`? It gives us more info to work with.

Comment: One thing I notice is that these rows seem quite large. I would recommend specifying the columns you need in the select instead of using the wildcard.

Comment: The execution plan is better shared as formatted text (the same way you shared your query), not as a screen shot.

Comment: @BlueStar added EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) , but I need all of them for page(

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have problems with formatted text. It's always ugly. I am trying formatted now

Comment: @HansKeﬆing added pk and fk. I tried index by (refuel_request_status_id , created_at DESC) , tried just created_at DESC , and many other

Comment: Could you please use plain text instead of images? I can read that image, but there is no way I can use any tooling like https://explain.depesz.com that gives me the information I'm looking for.

Comment: Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All outer joind tables are 1:n related to `refuel_request`. This means your query is looking for the last ten created refuel requests with status 1 to 3.

You are outer joining the tables, because not every `reful_request` is related to a `user`, a `bill_qr`, a `car`, and a `status`. Or you outer join mistakenly. Anyway, none of the joins changes the number of retrieved rows; it's still one row per refuel request. In order to join the other tables' rows the DBMS just needs their primary key indexes. Nothing to worry about.

The only thing we must care about is finding the top `reful_request` rows for the statuses you are interested in as quickly as possible.

Use a partial index that only contains data for the statuses in question. The column you index is the `created_at` column, so as to get the top 10 immediately.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON refuel_request (created_at DESC)
                 WHERE refuel_request_status_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Partial indexes are explained here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html

Comment: Ty, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

You need at least the indexes for the joins (do you really need LEFT joins?)

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "user" AS "user" ON "refuel_request"."user_id" = "user"."user_id"
```

So, refuel_request.user_id must be in the index

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "bill_qr" AS "bill_qr" ON "refuel_request"."bill_qr_id" = 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "car" AS "order.car" ON "refuel_request"."car_id" =
```

bill_qr_id and car_id too

```
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "refuel_request_status" AS "refuel_request_status" ON "refuel_request"."refuel_request_status_id" =
```

and refuel_request_status_id

```
 WHERE
  refuel_request."refuel_request_status_id" IN ( '1', '2', '3')
```

refuel_request_status_id must be the first key in the index as we need it in the WHERE

```
 ORDER BY "refuel_request".created_at desc
```

and then created_at since it's in the `ORDER` clause. This will not improve performances *per se*, but will allow to run the ORDER BY without requiring access to the table data, the same reason why we put the other non-WHERE columns in there. Of course a partial index is even better, we shift the WHERE in the partiality clause and use `created_at` for the rest (the LIMIT 10 now means that we can do without the extra columns in the index, since retrieving three 1:N rows costs very little; in a different situation we might find it useful to keep those extra columns).

So one index that contains, in this order:

```
 refuel_request_status_id, created_at, bill_qr_id, car_id too, user_id
 ^ WHERE                   ^ ORDER     ^ used by the JOINS
```

However, do you really need a `SELECT *`? I believe you'd get better performances if you only included the fields you're really going to use.

Comment: I had tried to include the fields I really want but it not change performance. 
Now I trying to add index refuel_request_status_id, created_at, bill_qr_id, car_id, user_id and let you know how performance chaged

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe actually yes, I can. The query will be done on the index; granted, having a partial index is the correct solution, but even this way the first stage of the join only needs to access the one index. Unless the costs for the additional columns selected make it worthwhile to do a sequential scan, but that's another problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe wait, there is a misunderstanding. I was not going to rely on the index for the ORDER BY -- I only wanted it for its data. Same way a covering index is used, if you will. The advantage is that the ORDER BY does not need to access the *table*. I still expect the server to require a full scan *of the index*, that's a given (added to the answer so it's clearer).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an index that supports both the `WHERE` condition and the `ORDER BY`, because you are using `IN` and not `=`.

The fastest option is to split the query into three parts, so that each part compares `refuel_request.refuel_request_status_id` with `=`. Combine these three queries with `UNION ALL`. Each of the queries has `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 10`, and you wrap the whole thing in an outer query that has another `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 10`.

Then you need these indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON refuel_request (refuel_request_status_id, created_at);
CREATE INDEX ON "user" (user_id);
CREATE INDEX ON bill_qr (bill_qr_id);
CREATE INDEX ON car (car_id);
CREATE INDEX ON refuel_request_status (refuel_request_status_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

The most effective index for this query would be on refuel_request (refuel_request_status_id, created_at DESC) so that both the main filtering and the ordering can be done using the index. You also want indexes on the columns you're joining, but those tables are small and inconsequential at the moment. In any case, the index I suggest isn't actually going to help much with the performance pain points you're having right now. Here are some suggestions:

1. Don't use `SELECT *` unless you really need all of the columns from all of these tables you're joining. Specifying only the necessary columns means postgres can load less data into memory, and work over it faster.
2. Postgres is spending a lot of time on the joins, joining about a million rows each time, when you're really only interested in ten of those rows. We can encourage it do the order/limit first by rearranging the query somewhat:

```sql
WITH refuel_request_subset AS MATERIALIZED (
    SELECT *
    FROM refuel_request
    WHERE refuel_request_status_id IN ('1', '2', '3')
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 10
)
SELECT *
FROM refuel_request_subset AS refuel_request
LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON refuel_request.user_id = user.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN bill_qr ON refuel_request.bill_qr_id = bill_qr.bill_qr_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN car AS "order.car" ON refuel_request.car_id = "order.car".car_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN refuel_request_status ON refuel_request.refuel_request_status_id = refuel_request_status.refuel_request_status_id;
```

Note: This assumes that the `LEFT JOINS` will not add rows to the result set, as is the case with your current dataset.

3. This trick only really works if you have a fixed number of IDs, but you can do the `refuel_request_subset` query separately for each ID and then `UNION` the results, as opposed to using the `IN` operator. That would allow postgres to fully use the index mentioned above.

Comment: You cannot have an index that supports both the `WHERE` condition and the `ORDER BY` in this case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I know that, and mentioned in suggestion 3 that they'll need to use a `UNION` to use both columns of the index, similarly to what you answered. I guess I wasn't clear enough, though.